# Saving an array in matlab efficiently

Tags: matlab

I want to save an array efficiently in matlab. I have the array of size 3000 by 9000. If I save this array in the mat file it consumes around 214 MB using just the save function. If I use fwrite and use float data type came to be around 112. Is there any other way that I can still reduce the hard disk space consumed when I save this array in matlab?

Comment: I assume you have double numbers? Then not much can be done. One possibility would be to convert them to integers (e.g. multiplying by 1000) and save as integers. Then after reading converting them back to doubles. But it depends on the nature of your data and how much precision you need.

Comment: 3000 × 9000 elements × 8 bytes per element = 216 MB. You could compress this, but unless your data has some sort of underlying structure, this will help marginally...Do you happen to have a lot of zeros or other repeated elements in your data? Can your data be generated easily by software?

Comment: I also don't think you can do much as Matlab files are already compressed by default. You could check in your preferences to make sure. btw. 200MB is nothing nowadays - is it really worth worrying?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing using [binary mode](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html) and then using compression algorithm such as bzip

Comment: Matlab mat files are already compressed binary files (plus a few 100 descriptive bytes) - I doubt there is much to gain.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to reduce the required memory:

### 1. Reducing precision

Rather than using that `double` you normally have, consider using a `single`, or perhaps even a `uint8` or `logical`. Using the print function will also so this, but you may want to consider compressing further afterwards as printing does not create a compressed file.

### 2. Utilizing a pattern

If your matrix has a certain pattern, this can sometimes be leveraged to store the data more efficiently. Or at least the information to create the data. The most common example is that your matrix is storeable as a few vectors. For example when it is `sparse`.